# crystal reports and visual studio 2019 community editor issues

Tags: crystal-reports, editor, visual-studio-2019

I have been having issues with newer versions of Crystal Reports (SP25 and SP26) in Visual Studio Community 2019.

At first glance, everything works OK, but after some  time editor stops responding, I cannot use any buttons from toolbars (even non-Crystal ones, like for saving). Usually I can click elements on report, but context menus also stop working, it's basically unusable.

Sometimes, when I switch focus between Visual Studio windows, things go back to normal, but for very short time. Other times, only Visual Studio restart helps.

I've been searching the web, but I cannot find awful lot about this issues. So, If somebody has similar issues with this, please assist. Or it's just me, and my machine?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are known issues in SP25. SP26 is supposed to address them. Are you sure you are seeing them with SP26?

Comment: Yes, SP26 installed. Improved over SP25, but still not very usable for me :(

Comment: Just to let you know, after fresh installation of SP26, everything is OK

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for closing the loop.